# 'ngcc' not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: angular, angular-compiler, angular-compiler-cli

Running command `npm run ngcc` throws the error `'ngcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ngcc": "ngcc"
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-extensions/elements": "^9.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/elements": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any mismatch in the version of anuglar-compiler and other packages? Not able to find the root cause of the issue. Can someone please help?

Comment: why you do want to run ngcc command instead of just ng build?

Comment: what is angular cli version?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried running "npm ci"? It fixed the problem for me, it seems my cli was not correctly installed. https://preview-docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/npm-ci

Comment: Still gives same error